# Google Mobile Vision iOS issue

Tags: ios, mobile, apple-vision, google-ios-vision

https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/getting-started

pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector' does not exist

pod install does not work

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: Updating to cocoapod 1.2.0 and it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your Podfile and the error detail to the question? I tried the pod and it works.

Here's what my Podfile looks like,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "FaceDetector" do
  pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'
end
```

Are you able to try out the samples?

```
pod try GoogleMobileVision
```

Answer (score 0):

use - > pod'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'
and link all frameworks in Project target->build phases -> link binaries with libraries.
It will work it definetly.

```
googlemobilevision.framework

facedetector.framework

GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framwrok

GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework

GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework

GoogleUtilities.framework
```